# ActiveRecord joins and where

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have three models Company, Deal and Slot. They are associated as Company has_many deals and Deal has_many slots. All the A company can be expired if all of its deals are expired. And a deal is expired when all of its slots are expired.

I have written a scope..

```
scope :expired,
  lambda { |within|
    self.select(
      'DISTINCT companies.*'
    ).latest(within).joins(
      :user =>{ :deals => :slots }
    ).where(
      "companies.spam = false AND deals.deleted_at IS NULL
        AND deals.spam = false AND slots.state = 1 
        OR slots.begin_at <= :time",
      :time => Time.zone.now + SLOT_EXPIRY_MARGIN.minutes
    )
  }
```

The above scope does not seem right to me from what I am trying to achieve. I need companies with all of its slots for all the deals are either in state 1 or the begin_at is less than :time making it expired.

Thanks for having a look in advance.

Comment: It was dizzyingly hard to read on a single line so I've split it up.

Answer (score 1):

AND has a higher precedence than OR in SQL so your `where` actually gets parsed like this:

```
(
        companies.spam = false
    and deals.deleted_at is null
    and deals.spam = false
    and slots.state = 1
)
or slots.begin_at <= :time
```

For example (trimmed a bit for brevity):

```
mysql> select 1 = 2 and 3 = 4 or 5 = 5;
+---+
| 1 |
+---+

mysql> select (1 = 2 and 3 = 4) or 5 = 5;
+---+
| 1 |
+---+

mysql> select 1 = 2 and (3 = 4 or 5 = 5);
+---+
| 0 |
+---+
```

Also, you might want to use a placeholder instead of the literal `false` in the SQL, that should make things easier if you want to switch databases (but of course, database portability is largely a myth so that's just a suggestion); you could also just use `not` in the SQL. Furthermore, [using a class method is the preferred way to accept arguments for scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments). Using `scoped` instead of `self` is also a good idea in case other scopes are already in play but if you use a class method, you don't have to care.

If we fix the grouping in your SQL with some parentheses, use a placeholder for `false`, and switch to a class method:

```
def self.expired(within)
  select('distinct companies.*').
  latest(within).
  joins(:user => { :deals => :slots }).
  where(%q{
        not companies.spam
    and not deals.spam
    and deals.deleted_at is null
    and (slots.state = 1 or slots.begin_at <= :time)
  }, :time => Time.zone.now + SLOT_EXPIRY_MARGIN.minutes)
end
```

You could also write it like this if you prefer little blobs of SQL rather than one big one:

```
def self.expired(within)
  select('distinct companies.*').
  latest(within).
  joins(:user => { :deals => :slots }).
  where('not companies.spam').
  where('not deals.spam').
  where('deals.deleted_at is null').
  where('slots.state = 1 or slots.begin_at <= :time', :time => Time.zone.now + SLOT_EXPIRY_MARGIN.minutes)
end
```

This one also neatly sidesteps your "missing parentheses" problem.

---

**UPDATE**: Based on the discussion in the comments, I think you're after something like this:

```
def self.expired(within)
  select('distinct companies.*').
  latest(within).
  joins(:user => :deals).
  where('not companies.spam').
  where('not deals.spam').
  where('deals.deleted_at is null').
  where(%q{
      companies.id not in (
          select company_id
          from slots
          where state     = 1
            and begin_at <= :time
          group by company_id
          having count(*) >= 10
      )
  }, :time => Time.zone.now + SLOT_EXPIRY_MARGIN.minutes
end
```

That bit of nastiness at the bottom grabs all the company IDs that have ten or more expired or used slots and then `companies.id not in (...)` excludes them from the final result set.

Comment: Its always good to know more best practices. But my problem is not yet solved. The query also fetches the companies which have mixed slots expired(satisfying the above condition) and unexpired. I am sorry I am terribly bad at Mysql. Please have a look at this log. [link](http://s1079.photobucket.com/albums/w518/vikramkohli87/?action=view&current=Screenshotat2012-03-15022221.png)

Comment: @Vikram: Do you actually want `slots.state = 1 and slots.begin_at <= :time` then? I don't know your schema so I'm making some guesses.

Comment: A company is expired when all the slots are either sold(state = 1) or the slots are no longer valid(slots.begin_at <= :time). If a company has even a single slot that is not expired or not invalid, the company is not expired. From the above scheme it also returns the company with only 1 slot expired/invalid out of 10. What I want is, it should only return company only if all 10 slots are expired/invalid.

Comment: @Vikram: Have a look at my update please, I think I understand what you're after.

Comment: Thanks @mu , The solution worked for me. I just had to modify a bit to suit my needs.

Comment: The modified version of the method.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to StackOverflow. Pressing enter adds the comment:).
the modified version of the method is.
`def self.expired(within)
     select('distinct deals.*').
     latest(within).
     joins(:slots).
     where("(NOT deals.spam)").
     where(%q{
         deals.id not in (
            :active
         )
     }, {:time => Time.zone.now + SLOT_EXPIRY_MARGIN.minutes, :active => active(within).map(&:id)}).
     includes([:user, :service, :slots])
   end`

Comment: Bloody "enter" without a "shift".. and here it is for company.
inline `def self.expired(within)
    select('distinct companies.*').
    latest(within).
    joins(:user => :deals).
    where('not companies.spam').
    where("companies.status = 'active'").
    where('deals.deleted_at is null').
    where(%q{
        companies.id not in (:active)
    }, {:time => Time.zone.now + SLOT_EXPIRY_MARGIN.minutes, :active => active(within).map(&:id)}).
    includes({:user => :deals}) 
  end`

I just have to stuff in the companies without any deals too.After this one I am sure I am going to study "mysql".